# Rails Admin - Exclude actions in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I am newest a Rails Admin and I have written a custom action to toggle a record active with an play & pause icons. I would like to exclude the action in others model.

Here is my custom action

```rb
# lib/rails_admin/custom_actions.rb
module RailsAdmin
  module Config
    module Actions
     class MemberAction < RailsAdmin::Config::Actions::Base
        register_instance_option :member? do
          true
        end
        register_instance_option :visible do
          true
        end
     end
     class ToggleActive < MemberAction
        RailsAdmin::Config::Actions.register(self)
        register_instance_option :only do
          ['FirstJob', 'Internship']
        end
        register_instance_option :http_methods do
          [:get, :post]
        end
        register_instance_option :link_icon do
          subject = bindings[:object]
          icon = subject.active ? 'icon-pause' : 'icon-play'
        end

        register_instance_option :controller do
          Proc.new do
            @object.active = !@object.active
            if @object.save!
              flash[:notice] = "#{@object.title} is now #{ @object.active ? 'actived' : 'desactivated'}"
              redirect_to back_or_index
            else
              flash[:notice] = "Toggle activation of #{object.title} did not worked"
              redirect_to back_or_index
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I have a model `Profile` and I want to exclude `ToggleActive`. 
I tried this one :

```rb
# config/initializers/rails_admin.rb

RailsAdmin.config do |config|
 config.actions do
    dashboard                     

    # breadcrumb actions
    index                         
    new
    export

    # selected items actions
    bulk_delete
    bulk_activate
    bulk_desactivate

    # inline item actions
    show
    edit
    delete
    show_in_app
    toggle_active do
      except 'Profile'
    end
 end
end
```

But it's still loading the `ToggleActive` action and try to find the method `active` for `Profile`. So it raises :

```
undefined method `active' for #<Profile:0x00007fd9b7932c98>
```

If I add `unless condition`, it is working but I am not sure it is the proper way to do this.

```rb
# lib/rails_admin/custom_actions.rb
icon = subject.active ? 'icon-pause' : 'icon-play' unless subject.class == Profile
```

Thanks !!!

Comment: For your `unless` workaround, you can check it by `subject.is_a?(Profile)`. Much simpler and does not involve a costy equal check.

Comment: Thanks ! So I edit the visibility like this and it works :
```ruby
        register_instance_option :visible do
          @subject = bindings[:object]
          !@subject.is_a?(Profile)
        end
```

Comment: You missed an `if` before the expression, but otherwise, yes. Or `@subject = @subject.is_a?(Profile) ? bindings[:object] : nil` could also help if you have a falsy value for @subject.